# Multiple array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando traer informacion de dos dos tablas

1. la primer tabla (separacion) me muestra el id de separacion y hora de ingreso
2. la segunda tabla (separacion_detalle) me muestra que calidades contiene esa separacion, como se puede observar en la imagen, es un ejemplo de como deberia quedar.

mi controlador:

```
    public function add(){
        $data = array(
                'separaciones' => $this->Modeltarima->getSeparaciones(),
                'calidades' => $this->Modeltarima->getDetalle(50) 
//Aqui no entiendo como puedo hacer esto, ¿array bidimensional? se puede ver que solo pase el numero "50" para hacer la prueba de la imagen.
            );
        $this->load->view('content/head');
        $this->load->view('content/aside');
        $this->load->view('pages/proceso/tarimas/viewgenerar',$data);
        $this->load->view('content/footer');
        $this->load->view('content/scrips/proceso/srcontrols');
    }
```

Mi modelo:

```
public function getDetalle($id){
    $this->db->select('a.*,d.id as idcal, d.nombre as cal');
    $this->db->from('separacion_detalles a');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->join('calidad d', 'a.calidad = d.id');
    $this->db->where('a.separacion',$id);
    $result = $this->db->get('separacion_detalles');
    return $result->result();
}
```

`getDetalle(id)` lo que hace es retornar el nombre de las calidades que pertenecen a esa separacion.

```
public function getSeparaciones(){
    $result = $this->db->get('separacion');
    return $result->result();
}
```

`getSeparacion(id)` simplemente mostramos las separaciones que hay registradas.

Algo un poco explicado en json de como lo imagino

```
    "separaciones": [{
        "id": "50",
        "hora": "15:04:12",
        "calidades":[ {
            "id":"10",
            "nombre":"CUARTA",
            "cajas":0
          },
           {
            "id":"30",
            "nombre":"CALIBRE 12?S",
            "cajas":0
          },
         ]
    },
{
        "id": "51",
        "hora": "13:04:00",
        "calidades":[ {
            "id":"10",
            "nombre":"CUARTA",
            "cajas":0
          },
           {
            "id":"30",
            "nombre":"CALIBRE 12?S",
            "cajas":0
          },
         ]
    }
    ]
```

¿Como podria hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo puedes hacer muy simple fusionando tus 2 funciones así:

```
public function getSeparaciones(){
    //obtienes todas las separaciones en un array
    $separaciones = $this->db->get('separacion')->result_array();

    //haces un foreach para recorrer el array
    foreach ($separaciones as $key => $value) {
        //luego obtienes las calidades por cada separacion
        $this->db->select('a.*,d.id as idcal, d.nombre as cal');
        $this->db->from('separacion_detalles a');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->join('calidad d', 'a.calidad = d.id');
        $this->db->where('a.separacion',$value['id']);
        $result = $this->db->get('separacion_detalles');
        //luego insertas en el array las calidades por separación
        $separaciones[$key]['calidades']=$result->result_array();
    }
    //por ultimo retornas el array de separaciones
    return $separaciones;
}
```

Luego en tu controlador llamas a tu función y codificas el array en json:

```
$this->load->model('datos_model');
$data['json']=json_encode($this->datos_model->getSeparaciones());
$this->load->view('vista', $data);
```

y para mostrar los datos en tu vista puedes utilizar 2 `foreach`así:

```
$separaciones=json_decode($json);
foreach ($separaciones as $value) {
    echo 'id:'.$value->id.'<br>';
    echo 'hora: '.$value->hora.'<br>Calidades: ';
    foreach ($value->calidades as $key) {
        echo '(id:'.$key->id.',';
        echo 'nombre:'.$key->nombre.',';
        echo 'cajas:'.$key->cajas.')';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

De esa forma ya tienes lo que querías mostrar en tu json, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: y en php como podria mostrar esa información? usaba _<?php echo $separacions->id; ?>_ ahora como debe ser para recorrer el array de calidades?

Comment: puedes usar otro `foreach` así: `foreach ($separaciones as $value) { /*codigo*/ foreach ($value['calidades'] as $value2) { echo $value2['nombre'].','; } }` por ejemplo

Comment: me tira un error en _$this->db->where('a.idseparacion',$value['id']);_ **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Comment: Disculpa @ManuelMorales, estoy confundiendo objetos con arrays, ya edite la respuesta

Comment: una pregunta donde debería ir el _where_ para filtrar la tabla separación por fecha?

Comment: @ManuelMorales puedes usar `$separaciones = $this->db->get_where('separacion', array('fecha' => '2018-04-21'))->result_array();` para buscar una separación en una fecha